# SqlBulkCopy for datatables having inner datatables in c# console application

Tags: c#, json, sql-server

I have a datatable with 15 columns out of which 2 columns contain inner datatables containing 5 columns each. Is it possible to break hierarchy and add inner datatable columns to main datatable columns?
Or can I seperate those 2 columns from datatable and load them into different sql server table?
Inner datatables are formed by reading JSONArray object with multiple values.

I use following code part to Deserialize JSON into Datatable

```
var dtset = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(JSON);
```

My JSON looks like below,

```
 [{
    "cpty": "SG, LP",
    "internallegalentity": "ABC, LN",
    "createdate": null,
    "paymentcurrency": "USD",
    "id": 123,
    "version": 1,
    "revisiondate": "2020-01-31 12:33:39.714",
    "amount": -4.25,
    "duedate": "2020-01-29",
    "asofdate": "2020-02-25",
    "isdeleted": false,
    "source": "XYZ",
    "isprovisional": null,
    "isproforma": null,
    "items": [{
        "id": 123,
        "amount": -4.25,
        "currency": "USD",
        "itemid": 15505,
        "quantity": 1600.0,
        "unit": "MWh",
        "enddate": "2020-02-29",
        "startdate": "2020-02-01",
        "transactiondate": "2020-01-29",
        "description": "Cash",
        "price": 1.0
    }],
    "payments": [{
            "createdate": "2020-02-12T00:00:00Z",
            "transactiondate": "2020-02-11T12:00:00Z",
            "paymentmethod": "Check",
            "amount": 100.0,
            "paymentcurrency": "USD",
            "id": 123
        },
        {
            "createdate": "2020-02-12T00:00:00Z",
            "transactiondate": "2020-02-12T11:30:00Z",
            "paymentmethod": "Check",
            "amount": 100.0,
            "paymentcurrency": "USD",
            "id": 123
        }
    ]
},
{
    "counterparty": "AU",
    "internallegalentity": "xyc, LP",
    "createdate": null,
    "paymentcurrency": "USD",
    "id": 125,
    "version": 1,
    "revisiondate": "2020-01-31 12:33:39.922",
    "amount": -5120.0,
    "duedate": "2020-01-30",
    "asofdate": "2020-02-25",
    "isdeleted": false,
    "source": "XYZ",
    "isprovisional": null,
    "isproforma": null,
    "items": [{
            "id": 125,
            "amount": -1280.0,
            "currency": "USD",
            "itemid": 15508,
            "quantity": 64000.0,
            "unit": "MWh",
            "enddate": "2021-02-28",
            "startdate": "2021-01-01",
            "transactiondate": "2020-01-30",
            "description": "Cash",
            "price": 1.0
        },
        {
            "id": 125,
            "amount": -1280.0,
            "currency": "USD",
            "itemid": 15507,
            "quantity": 64000.0,
            "unit": "MWh",
            "enddate": "2021-02-28",
            "startdate": "2021-01-01",
            "transactiondate": "2020-01-30",
            "description": "Cash",
            "price": 1.0
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Is there any way to read above JSON in more approprate way?

Comment: Your posted `Json` is not correct how the community member would help you!

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron My Apologies. I validated JSON and updated my question to valid JSON code.

Comment: Could you also add something around the database schema please? I assume you have something like a Main and then Main_Payments and Main_Items with appropriate relationships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the real struggle you're having is not so much about the bulk copy aspect per se, but about flattening out the datatables.  So aside from some simple code at the end, I'll really focus on that problem.

By the way, this is how you represent json in c# (fill in the elipsies of course):

```
static string json = @"
[
    {
        ""cpty"": ""SG, LP"",
        ""internallegalentity"": ""ABC, LN"",
        ""createdate"": null,
        ""paymentcurrency"": ""USD"",
        ""id"": 123,
        ""version"": 1,
        ...
    },
    ...
]";
```

First, create three DataTable variables.  The first is your parsed json data, the other two are empty ones to receive your items and payments data:

```
DataTable jsonTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json);
DataTable items = null;
DataTable payments = null;
```

Next, loop through your parsed json data and extract your nested datatables into their variable counterparts.  On the first pass, you'll want to copy the tables into their respective variables.  On subsequent passes, you'll want to merge the tables into the variables.  And be careful for the DBNull result in your payments field.

```
foreach (DataRow row in jsonTable.Rows) {

    // get the inner "items" 
    var jsonItems = (DataTable)row["items"];

    if (items == null) 
        items = jsonItems.Copy(); // first pass
    else 
        items.Merge(jsonItems); // subsequent passes

    // there is a null payments record, ignore it
    if (row["payments"] == DBNull.Value)
        continue;

    // get the inner payments
    var jsonPayments = (DataTable)(row["payments"]);

    if (payments == null)
        payments = jsonPayments.Copy(); // first not null pass
    else 
        payments.Merge(jsonPayments); // subsequent passes

}
```

Now that you have the items and payments tables, delete those fields from your originally parsed table:

```
jsonTable.Columns.Remove("items");
jsonTable.Columns.Remove("payments");
```

You are now ready to bulk copy as appropriate.  The following untested code assumes you already have existing tables with columns in the same order as your datatable representations.

```
using (var bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy("connection string")) {

    bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "main";
    bulkcopy.WriteToServer(jsonTable);

    bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "items";
    bulkcopy.WriteToServer(items);

    bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "payments";
    bulkcopy.WriteToServer(payments);

}
```

Comment: thanks @pwilcox , Exactly what I was looking for. Never thought this road. works perfectly fine.